# Adding JavaScript hotkeys to date controls for increased efficiency entering date values

Tags: javascript, date, devexpress

When editing a date input, I would like to add hotkeys for increased efficiency, such as:

- T : inputs todays date
- M : if empty, inputs 1 month from today, adds 1 month if date present
- Q : if empty, inputs 3 months from today (quarter year), add 3 months if date present
- Y : if empty, inputs 1 year from day, adds 1 year if date present
- (+) : if empty, inputs todays date, adds 1 day if date present
- (-) : if empty, inputs todays date, subtracts 1 day if date present

I use DevExpress ASPxDateEdit controls for my .net web forms projects, so my javascript reflects that. The code could be modified however to work with native HTML or other platforms.

My JavaScript doesn't work correctly when advancing a date. When it gets to another year, the date reverts back to this year. Advice or suggestions?

Here's what I wrote:

```
function DateHotKey(s, e) {
var c = e.htmlEvent.code;
var k = e.htmlEvent.key;

if (isNaN(parseFloat(k))) {
    switch (c) {

        case "KeyT":

            var retdate = new Date();
            s.SetValue(retdate);
            ASPxClientUtils.PreventEventAndBubble(htmlEvent);
            break;

        case "KeyM":

            var currdate = s.GetDate()
            if (currdate === null) {
                currdate = new Date();
            }
            var newDate = new Date(new Date().setMonth((currdate.getMonth() + 1)) );
            s.SetDate(newDate);
            ASPxClientUtils.PreventEventAndBubble(htmlEvent);
            break;

        case "KeyQ":  // Advance date by quarter

            var currdate = s.GetDate()
            if (currdate === null) {
                currdate = new Date();
            }
            var newDate = new Date(new Date().setMonth((currdate.getMonth() + 3)));

            s.SetDate(newDate);
            ASPxClientUtils.PreventEventAndBubble(htmlEvent);
            break;

        case "KeyY":

            var today = new Date();
            var newDate = new Date(new Date().setDate(today.getDate() + 365));
            s.SetDate(newDate);
            ASPxClientUtils.PreventEventAndBubble(htmlEvent);
            break;

        default:

            switch (k) {

                case "+":
                    var currdate = s.GetDate();
                    if (currdate === null) {
                        currdate = new Date();
                    }
                    var newDate = new Date(new Date().setDate(currdate.getDate() + 1));
                    s.SetDate(newDate);
                    ASPxClientUtils.PreventEventAndBubble(htmlEvent);
                    break;

                case "-":
                    var currdate = s.GetDate();
                    if (currdate === null) {
                        currdate = new Date();
                    }
                    var newDate = new Date(new Date().setDate(currdate.getDate() - 1));
                    s.SetDate(newDate);
                    ASPxClientUtils.PreventEventAndBubble(htmlEvent);
                    break;
            }
            break;
    } } }
```

Comment: What is *s*? Clearly not a standard ECMAScript *Date* object. What does `s.GetDate()` return?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clearer.  I'd indicated in the description that I use the DevExpress ASPxDateEdit controls. The small s represents the control that's passed to the function.  The ASPxDateEdit control has a GetDate() method and a SetDate() method. TThe way the function is called is:                                                     <dx:ASPxDateEdit ID="date_onset" runat="server">
                                                        <ClientSideEvents KeyUp="function(s,e) { DateHotKey(s,e) }" /></dx:ASPxDateEdit> where s is the subject control, and e represents any event parameters

Comment: The DevExpress ASPxDateEdit control, GetDate() returns the current date of the control, and SetDate() puts a date into the control.  https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNet/js-ASPxClientDateEdit.GetDate

Comment: You should add a DevExpress tag (there are a few, pick the most relevant) to the question, likely it needs someone with knowledge of both technologies to answer the question.

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks!  I think however the problem with my code is not related to DevExpress.  The logic flaw is somewhere in the JavaScript "var newDate = new Date(new Date().setMonth((currdate.getMonth() + 1)) );"  Each time the M key is pressed, the date is incremented by one month UNTIL the month is December. JavaScript then increments the month and REVERTS the year back to what it was.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved the problem. In my original code, I'm creating a new Date() object based on the current system date, then adding or subtracting based on the date value passed in. Here's the corrected code:

```
function DateHotKey(s, e) {
var c = e.htmlEvent.code;
var k = e.htmlEvent.key;

if (isNaN(parseFloat(k))) {
    switch (c) {

        case "KeyT":

            var retdate = new Date();
            s.SetValue(retdate);
            ASPxClientUtils.PreventEventAndBubble(htmlEvent);
            break;

        case "KeyM":

            var currdate = s.GetDate()
            if (currdate === null) {
                currdate = new Date();
            }
            var newDate = new Date(new Date(currdate).setMonth((currdate.getMonth() + 1)) );
            s.SetDate(newDate);
            ASPxClientUtils.PreventEventAndBubble(htmlEvent);
            break;

        case "KeyQ":  // Advance date by quarter

            var currdate = s.GetDate()
            if (currdate === null) {
                currdate = new Date();
            }
            var newDate = new Date(new Date(currdate).setMonth((currdate.getMonth() + 3)));

            s.SetDate(newDate);
            ASPxClientUtils.PreventEventAndBubble(htmlEvent);
            break;

        case "KeyY":

            var today = new Date();
            var newDate = new Date(new Date(currdate).setDate(today.getDate() + 365));
            s.SetDate(newDate);
            ASPxClientUtils.PreventEventAndBubble(htmlEvent);
            break;

        default:

            switch (k) {

                case "+":
                    var currdate = s.GetDate();
                    if (currdate === null) {
                        currdate = new Date();
                    }
                    var newDate = new Date(new Date(currdate).setDate(currdate.getDate() + 1));
                    s.SetDate(newDate);
                    ASPxClientUtils.PreventEventAndBubble(htmlEvent);
                    break;

                case "-":
                    var currdate = s.GetDate();
                    if (currdate === null) {
                        currdate = new Date();
                    }
                    var newDate = new Date(new Date(currdate).setDate(currdate.getDate() - 1));
                    s.SetDate(newDate);
                    ASPxClientUtils.PreventEventAndBubble(htmlEvent);
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
}}
```

Note the change from:

```
var newDate = new Date(new Date()...
```

To:

```
var newDate = new Date(new Date(currdate)...
```

I fixed the logic flaw by creating the newDate variable passing along the currDate. That way, when the year rolls over, the correct year goes along with it. If I've missed anything, please let me know. If anyone wants this function without DevExpress, i.e., native HTML, let me know.